# Insert query with update on conflict only when values aren't null

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-null

I have a query which goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO accounts(id, description, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count)
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
SET description=EXCLUDED.description, 
    followers_count=EXCLUDED.followers_count, 
    friends_count=EXCLUDED.friends_count, 
    statuses_count=EXCLUDED.statuses_count;
```

Now `description, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count` can all be NULL. My question is whether this query can be changed to only update when these values aren't NULL.

For example when:
`description='joey tribbiani'`
`followers_count=45`
`friends_count=90`
`statuses_count=15` don't update with NULL values. But when it's the other way around, do the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use coalesce():

```
INSERT INTO accounts(id, description, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count)
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
SET description = coalesce(EXCLUDED.description, accounts.description), 
    followers_count = coalesce(EXCLUDED.followers_count, accounts.followers_count),
    friends_count = coalesce(EXCLUDED.friends_count, accounts.friends_count),
    statuses_count = coalesce(EXCLUDED.statuses_count, accounts.statuses_count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COALESCE()` in the `SET` clause:

```
INSERT INTO accounts(id, description, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count)
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
SET description     = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.description, description)
    followers_count = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.followers_count, followers_count), 
    friends_count   = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.friends_count, friends_count), 
    statuses_count  = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.statuses_count, statuses_count);
```

When the value given for `insert` is `null`, this falls back on the original table value, which turns the assignment to a no-op.